# Lately/recently with past simple

Tags: word-choice

Can I use past simple with *recently* and *lately*?

"She recently/lately started to eat during breaks not after work."
Does the sentence  sound natural, or is it better to rephrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lately) says about ***lately***:

> ***Lately*** is usually used with ***perfect tenses*** (for example ‘*I have been*’), ***not with the simple past*** (for example ‘I was’). You say:
>
> - I’ve been very busy lately.
>
> Don’t say:
>
> - <del>I was very busy lately.</del>

The same dictionary, quoted by the [grammarexchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/recently-lately) adds:

> You can use ***recently*** with the *simple past* tense to talk about *something that happened not long ago.*
>
> - They recently got married.
>
> So, the main difference in usage between ‘*recently*’ and ‘*lately*’ is that *‘**recently**’ can be used with the simple past*, but *‘**lately**’ cannot*.

Your sentence however, does not refer to something that happened not long ago, but to something that has *started* not long ago and is still going on, in which case the present perfect is indicated. So it is better to say:

> Lately/Recently she has started to eat during breaks, not after work.

I introduced a comma to enhance contrast, but you can do without it.